# what are the azimuths of the different views of this object?

Tags: geometry

I think azimuths are probably not a big deal but I've been trying to figure out how to calculate them and somehow I keep getting confused.

I have a few images of a vehicle from different angles. (Shown at the bottom of this post).
In layman's terms I can just say that:

- image 1: view from the back of the car ($0^\circ$). we'll refer to this image in the other images below...
- image 2: now the car has moved $45^\circ$ to the right from previous position, so it's a total of $45^\circ$ from image 1
- image 3: now the car has moved $45^\circ$ to the right from previous position, and a total of $90^\circ$ from image 1
- image 4: now the car has moved $45^\circ$ to the right from previous position, and a total of $135^\circ$ from image 1
- image 5: now the car has moved $45^\circ$ to the right from previous position, and a total of $180^\circ$ from image 1

and so on...

Now, in the first image, the vehicle is pointing straight ahead (let's assume this is north). So if I assume it's pointing to north, then my question is, what are the "azimuths" for these angles? Will they simply be $0^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $180^\circ$, and so on?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to notice: your text speaks of $30^\circ$ increments, but the pictures seem to be taken from angles differing by $45^\circ$, since the third picture is already a straight side view of the car.

Your question “what are the "azimuths" for these angles” is confusing (or confused?). An [azimuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) *is* an angle, usually the angle between due north and the direction of some imagined ray, e.g. the ray along which a person is looking. I *assume* you want the azimuth of the direction where the camera is pointing.

That would indeed change in $45^\circ$ increments (or $30^\circ$ if you go by the text not the pictures), starting at $0^\circ$ since it started out pointing north. The only thing that remains is getting the sign straight. Usually you have azimuth increasing from north to east, with $90^\circ$ corresponding to due east, so if you move around your car in a clockwise fashion, your viewing azimuth would increase. Your sequence however is counter-clockwise, therefore you'd have azimuths $0^\circ, -45^\circ, -90^\circ$ and so on, or equivalently $0^\circ, 315^\circ, 270^\circ, \dots$.

Comment: thanks! yes that was a mistake, it should have said it's incrementing by 45 degrees, not 30.